# AngularJS : IF Statement inside "ng-repeat"?

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using AngularJS `v1.2.9`.

Inside `ng-repeat`, how do i use check the value of object and do action based on condition?

In English, something like:

```
if `X` is not null, then show `X`. Is it possible?
```

Here's my `ng-repeat` skeleton:

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results">
    <div>{{ r.title }}</div>
    <div>{{ r.location }}</div>
    <!--
    if ( r.date!=="null" ) {
        <div>{{ r.date }}</div>
    } else {
        <div>Date not confirmed yet.</div>
    }
    -->
</li>
```

I need to show `r.date` if it is not null. If it is null, then i say something else.

Please kindly help. Thanks all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results">
  <!-- If r.date contains a value, show it -->
  <span ng-if="r.date">{{r.date}}</span>
  <!-- If r.date does not contain a value show placeholder text -->
  <span ng-if="!r.date">Date not confirmed yet.<span>
</li>
```

Also see [What does an exclamation mark before a variable mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491491/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-variable-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: I liked @PankajParkar's bind more. But as he says, if the placeholder text/content gets large using different tags would probably be preferred.

Comment: Yes.. that was good.. I mentioned your answer because you had already wrote it & don't wanted to repeat that again..

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Question wasn't much clear so here is what you wanted just by having `ng-bind` directive in place. If the content is bigger then you can switch to the way suggested by @JustOneMoreQuestion below.

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results" ng-if="r.date">
    <div ng-bind="r.date ? r.date : 'Date not confirmed yet.'"></div>
</li>
```

---

You could easily do by using `ng-if`

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results" ng-if="r.date">
    <!--
    if ( r.date!=="null" ) {
        {{ r.date }}
    }
    -->
</li>
```

OR go for a filter which will filter out those will create a collection of element which has `date` in it.

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results| filter: { date: '' }">
    <!--
    if ( r.date!=="null" ) {
        {{ r.date }}
    }
    -->
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for great help! But it is a bit misunderstood from what i want. (Sorry for that) I edited the question just now. Thank you :)

Comment: @夏期劇場 look at my edit, let me know if still im missing something

Answer (score 2):

Check this one,

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results" >
    <div data-ng-if="r.date !== 'null'">
        Your Date
    </div>
    <div data-ng-if="r.date == 'null'">
        Date not confirmed yet
     </div>
 </li>
```

Comment: forgot to remove ' single quote.. you can use data-ng-if="r.date !== null". like this

Comment: `data-ng-if="r.date"` is enough