# What does an exclamation mark means in if condition?

Tags: javascript, operators

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    if (!String.prototype.repeat) { 
      String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
        return new Array(n + 1).join(this);
      };
    }

    alert( "La".repeat(3) ); // LaLaLa
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I didn't understand the following line of code:

> if (!String.prototype.repeat)

Comment: It's Javascript. You should research Javascript boolean operators and if statements.

Comment: Yes, the `!` in this if statement is saying if not. Please see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491491/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-variable-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [relational operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator) meaning NOT.  In your example, it will return `true` if `String.prototype.repeat` does NOT exist.