# What does ! mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logic, logical-operators

I have the following expression:

```
!([BLANK] === 4) && "STRing" === "STRing"
```

My question is, what does the `!` symbol mean in this expression?

Comment: `&&` is called short circuit operator. And consider priority of operators.

Comment: BLANK is a Variable

Comment: i m asking what does the ! actually do to the to code !(var ===4 ) it returns false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does an exclamation mark before a variable mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491491/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-variable-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The `!` symbol is used to indicate whether the expression defined is `false` or not.

For example, `!(5==4)` would return `true`, since 5 is not equal to 4.

The equivalent in English would be `not`.

Some further tests:

```js
var Spectric = "cool";
console.log("Is 5 not equal to 4? "+!(5==4)); //true
console.log("Is 'foo' not equal to 'bar'? "+!("foo"=="bar")); //true
console.log("Is Spectric not equal to Spectric? "+!(Spectric==Spectric)); //false
```