# Run function only once when button is clicked? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I want the function home(); to execute only once. When the player chooses their weapon it creates a homepage button every time they click one of three buttons.
how can it run once so only one homepage button is created regardless of how many times the game is played again?
https://codepen.io/hamisakim/full/XWjVEbx

```
function home(){ const button = document.createElement("button");
           button.innerHTML = "Homepage";
            button.setAttribute("id",'homebutton')
              const postDiv = document.querySelector('#choices');
                postDiv.appendChild(button);
                

function buttonClick(e) {
  home();
  const choices = ["lapis", "papyrus", "scalpellus"];
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
    document.querySelector("#homepageText").innerHTML = '';
    document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML = 'choose below to play again!';
  document.getElementById('choices').removeEventListener('click',null);
```

Comment: so add a check if it has run

Comment: Please add a [mcve] or at least valid code with proper indentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function in JavaScript that can be called only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713564/function-in-javascript-that-can-be-called-only-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `home()` functions adds a `<button id='homebutton'>`, you could use JS to [check if that ID is already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-can-i-check-if-an-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom) in the DOM

```
function home() {
    if (!document.getElementById("homebutton")) {
        // Create button, since it's not yet there
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! this is a nice simple way to do it.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) any answers that might have helped you. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: will do. what does the ! on line 2 do? does this make it a "function expression"?

Comment: [Take a look at this @SamiHakim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491491/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-variable-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Add a check if it has run. A simple boolean

```
var hasHomeRun = false;
function home(){
  if (hasHomeRun) return;
  hasHomeRun = true;
  ...
```

Other option would be to check to see if the element exists

```
function home(){
  if (document.querySelector('#choices')) return;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this:

```js
window.runHome = false;
const home = function() {
  console.log('run home');
}
const buttonClick = function() {
  if(!window.runHome) {
    window.runHome = 1;
    home();
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick()">Click</button>
```