# JavaScript - conditional operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am a bit confused why the following two functions are equivalent.

```
//Function 1

function sumTo(n) {
   if (n === 0) return 0;  // base case
   return n + sumTo(n-1);  // inductive step
}

//Function 2
function sumTo(n) {
   return n ? n + sumTo(n-1) : 0;
}
```

In function 2, it uses the conditional operator where the condition is `n`. What does the condition `n` mean here? My major confusion is that `n` is not a boolean value, but why it can be evaluated as `True` or `False`? Even if it can, with some implicate type casting, where `0` can be interpreted as `False`, shouldn't it be `return n ? 0 : n + sumTo(n-1)` for the whole thing to make sense?
My guess is that `n` means `n !== 0`, but it looks so strange.

Comment: [What does an exclamation mark before a variable mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491491/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-variable-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested, by introducing any type of variable in a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), they are automatically [converted to their boolean equivalent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion).

The two functions are not strictly equivalent because the first one explicitly checks if the variable equals `0`, while the second one doesn't, so `n` will evaluate to `false` and return `0` if it contains any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value like `false`, `''`, `undefined` or whatever else.

```js
function sumTo(n) {
   if (n === 0) return 0;  // base case
   return n + sumTo(n-1);  // inductive step
}

sumTo(false); // Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

```js
function sumTo(n) {
   return n ? n + sumTo(n-1) : 0;
}

console.log(sumTo(false)); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript every type of data can be evaluated as a boolean. There are two boolean values possibles: `truthy` and `falsey` values.

Some **truthy** values are:

- Strings differents than `""`
- Numbers differents than `0`
- Boolean `true`

Some **falsey** values are:

- Strings like `""`
- Number `0`
- Boolean `false`
- `Null` and `undefined` values.

---

To convert a value into a boolean you can use the `!!` operator, known as the double not operator. It transform a value in **true** or **false** depends of its value (`truthy` or `falsey`).

---

> My guess is that n means n !== 0, but it looks so strange.

You are right, when evaluating a value like `n ?`, without a comparison argument like `n === "1"` or `n === "0"` JS transform the value into a boolean in accordance of its value (`truthy` or `falsey`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the behaviour of JavaScript. `n` is evaluated here to be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). It'll be similar if you place `n` in an if statement as well.

From the MDN link on Truthy:

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered true when encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, -0, 0n, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, in this case `n` means `n !== 0`, the same applies to empty strings for example `var str = ""`, if you run `if(str)` will return false in this case, because the string is empty